# Install tkinter table in Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

can tkinter table be used in raspberry pi?
if it can, could you teach me how to install it?
i used many tkinter button 40x30 button in one frame.
is it possible to change them with tkinter table?
i need each button variable to make an IC Checker update program.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter belongs to Python, not Raspberry Pi.

Raspbian has Python by default. So if you could use the Tkinter table in Python which installed in any other OS, you could use it in Raspbian too.